# Web Development rendering 2 divs in 1 row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I wanted to create a web page that shows two templates(divs)in one row with a database given to me.
wanted to use map to make it easy but it renders 1 in each row.

```
function createCard(){
   return(
    <div className="mr-md-1 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
      <div className="my-3 py-3">
        <h2 className="display-5">{props. Header}</h2>
        <p className="lead">{props.Discrip}</p>
      </div>
   <div className="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px">
      <img className="img-render" src={props.imgURL} alt="contoler-image" >
    </div>
  </div>);
}
```

data.map(createCard);

Comment: Forgot to add props in the createCard braces ignore that

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap. Add `d-flex` in className to the first div

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap. according to [flex-bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex) can use:

```
function createCard(){
   return(
    <div className="d-flex flex-row mr-md-1 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
      <div className="my-3 py-3">
        <h2 className="display-5">{props. Header}</h2>
        <p className="lead">{props.Discrip}</p>
      </div>
   <div className="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px">
      <img className="img-render" src={props.imgURL} alt="contoler-image" >
    </div>
  </div>);
}
```